# Graphics Card Dying?

Tags: graphics-card, visual-artifacts

Lately my laptop has been having these odd graphical glitches and artifacting, as seen here:

[image: graphical glitches]

I'm almost certain that this is not a driver or software issue as my laptop is a dual boot and I started seeing these symptoms on both OSes at the same time. So, what do you guys think? Is this just my graphics card reaching the end of its life? Is there something else this could be (I really don't want to replace this card D:)

Comment: It is plausible that it is the graphics chip or its dedicated memory if it has any. And it is certainly not unheard (e.g. the nvidia chips on Dell lattidute-D series tended to die after a year or two). But before drawing that conclusion you might want to test with an external monitor ans see if it shows the same glitches. (It should if the problem is in the laptop).

Comment: Yes; Its possible your GPU is dying;

Comment: The picture is very useful , but it would help if you would also describe what you see when it happens, and how it manifests itself as you observe it. How often does it happen, what areas of the screen it effects, what operations(programs) cause it more. Any relevent information you observed would add to the picture provided.

Comment: It tends to be a flickering issue, parts of the image flicker and jump around a bit. It seems to manifest most frequently when I have multiple visible windows stacked on top of each other (and oddly enough it _never_ effects my Web browser..)

Comment: that sounds more like a slowdown, or running in a mode that is slower? Is the laptop the style that has both on-cpu-die gpu and a extra gpu processing that is used for "speed"? because this style of fail is layering , screenbuffering looking type from what you also added. could be cooling of even the cpu (which could be hard tested by itself) or possible memory problem of the shared grafics memory. While it looks bleak, it might be fixable, clean and insure proper cooling, test seperated components, check for the operations and software of switching grafics engines. No Pat answer.